# How to hook after DBI reconnect

Tags: perl, database-connection, hook, dbi

I deal with a module which provides abstraction over [`DBI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) which automatically reconnects. I need to perform some actions after `DBI->connect.

Is there a way to add a hook there without modifying this module? I don't have luck finding it in the documentation. Did I miss something?

Comment: I assume you've read the [callbacks section](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Callbacks) of the documentation? It appears that you can add a callback to any method *except* connect! All I can think of is to monkey patch `DBI::connect` to call the real `connect` and then pass on the `$dbh` that it returns.

Answer (score 3):

The DBI doc has [a chapter about subclassing](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Subclassing-the-DBI) which mentions a `$dbh->connected` method that does nothing. It seems to be exactly what you want.

> When subclassing is being used then, after a successful new connect, the DBI->connect method automatically calls:
>
> ```
> $dbh->connected($dsn, $user, $pass, \%attr);
> ```

I have not tried that, but it might work by just monkey-patching this connected method into DBI directly without subclassing anything. [In `connect`](https://metacpan.org/source/TIMB/DBI-1.636/DBI.pm#L597) [there is definitely a call to `connected`](https://metacpan.org/source/TIMB/DBI-1.636/DBI.pm#L746).

But I am not sure where to patch that in. Possibly into the driver. A quick [grep of the cpan](http://grep.cpan.me/?q=dist%3ADBI%20sub%20connected) shows that only two drivers included in the DBI dist include this. [DBD::Gofer](https://metacpan.org/source/TIMB/DBI-1.636/lib/DBD/Gofer.pm#L273) and [DBD::Proxy](https://metacpan.org/source/TIMB/DBI-1.636/lib/DBD/Proxy.pm#L297), but that one is empty. In both of them it's in the `DBD::<drivername>::db` package.

Let's assume you are doing MySQL, then you'd go and hook it into your driver. Either by subclassing and using that driver, or by simply monkey-patching it in.

```
*DBD::mysql::db::connected = sub {
    my ($dbh, dsn, $user, $pass, $attr, $old_driver) = @_;

    warn 'Connected!';
}
```

This should work the same with other drivers, unless they have their own `connected`. In that case, you should probably wrap it manually or use something like [Class::Method::Modifiers](http://p3rl.org/Class::Method::Modifiers)'s `around` to wrap it to make sure the original behavior stays intact.

You also have the actual connected `$dbh` at this point, so you can go rummaging around in the database in `connected` if you want.

Of course this would give you the callback after *every connect*. If you wanted to only get the reconnects, you could create a closure over a lexical variable that counts the connections and skip the very first one.

```
{
    my $connection_counter;
    *DBD::mysql::db::connected = sub {
        my ($dbh, dsn, $user, $pass, $attr, $old_driver) = @_;
    
        return unless $connection_counter++; # skip first connection
        warn 'Connected!';
    }
}
```

Please note that I have not tested any of this.

Comment: I hope you're right, but the OP says *"I deal with a module which provides abstraction over DBI"* which they don't want to modify, so using a subclass doesn't seem possible. I guess subclassing the existing subclass may work though, if that's how the abstraction is done.

Comment: And thank you. You taught me about a corner of `DBI` that I wasn't aware of hitherto.

Comment: @Borodin I was not aware of it either. I got lucky skimming the docs. ;)

Comment: Nowadays you can use the `Callbacks` parameter. However, if you are using DBD::mysql and its `mysql_auto_reconnect` facility, the connected callback won't be called when reconnecting.

Answer (score 0):

While I must say I have not tried this; I found this article

http://justatheory.com/computers/databases/postgresql/execute-on-select.html

where @theory writes about an option to leverage DBI to run code whenever something happens - like connect. Hope it helps!